# why stringbuilder is not throwing concurrent modification exception when threads are writing and reading at same time

Tags: junit4, java.util.concurrent

i am trying to generate concurrent modification exception using junit test case. in this case as stringbuilder is not thread safe, it should give exception when read and write happens at the same time. i ran it multiple times and getting infinite loop output but no concurrent exception. how can i generate concurrent modification exception using this code?

```
package com.blog.article.threading.example;

public class Logger {

    private StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();

    public void log(String message) {
        contents.append(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        contents.append(message);
        contents.append("\n");
    }

    public String getContents() {
        return contents.toString();
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
package com.blog.article.threading.example;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoggerTest extends Thread {

    @InjectMocks
    Logger logger;

    @Test
    public void testWithStringBuilderObject() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (true) {
                        logger.log("A");
                        System.out.println(logger.getContents());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(20);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Main Thread");
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle dependency:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    repositories { jcenter() }

    dependencies { testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22' }
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it should throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: read and write operation is happening at the same time , logging of message and append method is being written as well as simultaneously read from other threads via getContents(). please correct if i am wrong.

Comment: Implementations have to throw this exception, as seen on http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l842. If the implementation of `StringBuilder` does not have such code then this exception is obviously not thrown.

Comment: i have gone through some links it mentions that stringbuilder is not thread safe. so how is safety ensured ?
also please suggest in which situations read and write is allowed vs not allowed (ie excep thrown) for java classes which are not thread safe.

Comment: It isn't. The documentation of that class say that it is not thread safe.

Comment: okay i got it now.  It comes for non thread safe collection classes as mentioned in their docs. 
for other non thread safe classes , their will be data inconsistency and as in this case.
Thank you !!